# Would "objectively necessary" convey that something is necessary as a matter of fact, regardless of opinions?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

In Russian "objectively necessary" (literal translation) means necessary as a matter of fact, not as a matter of judgement. Like, e.g., the water is objectively necessary for plants to grow.

Does this expression work in English for the purpose? If not, are there any alternative qualifiers?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Objectively necessary* will not be misunderstood, but it's not a common English collocation. A quick Google on the phrase suggests that it's peculiar to two contexts: Kantian and Marxist ethics, and deliberations of courts and regulatory agencies of the European Union. And in fact it's hard for me to imagine circumstances where you might be called on to insist that water is 'objectively' rather than 'subjectively' necessary for plant growth; bare *necessary* seems to be entirely adequate all by itself. I would reserve *objectively necessary* for situations in which objective and subjective interpretations might be at loggerheads—ethics and law, as a matter of fact!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess at the meaning of "objectively necessary", I suppose I might guess that it meant necessary as a matter of fact.  The trouble is, I don't know how to interpret *that*.  The difference between what is necessarily true and what is merely factually true is taken by logicians to be the difference between propositions that are true in all possible worlds and those that are true in our world, but not necessarily in other worlds.  Or, necessary propositions are taken to be logically demonstrable.

I have seen some discussion of "theoretical necessity" as as an alternative to "logical necessity".  Something that follows from the assumptions of a very well supported theory is theoretically necessary.  Maybe this is what you are looking for.

For discussion of types of necessity and references to the logical literature, see **Modal Logic and its Applications** by Donald Snyder.

Comment: Greg, you warmed my heart :) I graduated in mathematical logic (intuitionistic logic).

I presume, we all refer only to the truth or necessity in our world. At least, so do Russians, when saying "objectively necessary". Another interpretation of the meaning of that phrase would be

Comment: (submitted the previous comment in the middle of writing inadvertedly) 
Indeed, we cannot know that absolute necessity. 
Another interpretation of the meaning of that phrase would be "to the best of my knowledge, any reasonable man would obviously, easily, no doubts find that necessary" - now it is modal, right?
Something like, "It was objectively necessary that we got a car to get there in 5 min" - it was 5km from where we were, it would have taken an hour walking

Comment: Yes, I think your last example involves theoretical necessity in the sense I used it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **"unquestionably necessary"**.

- Water is unquestionably necessary, and so is sex.

> - unquestionably necessary - "necessary beyond doubt or dispute" [DRC](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unquestionably)